# Finding element with tabindex selector

Tags: java, selenium, tabindex

I have a problem with selecting the element with only tabindex selector

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1">
    <!--template bindings={}--><span><strong>D000002</strong></span>
  </a>
```

it looks like this:
[image]
, xpath copied from DevTool:`//*[@id="dcr-search-form"]/typeahead-container/ul/li/a/span/strong`
doesn't work:

```
query = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dcr-search-form']/typeahead-container/ul/li/a/span/strong"));
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dcr-search-form']/typeahead-container/ul"));

worked:)